# ActiveAdmin, register_page and register

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Given a page defined with:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Car do
  index do
    column :id
    column :number_plate
  end
end
```

I want to add a panel with some text before the items table.

Here is what I noticed about the availability of methods for customizing admin pages.

- when i create a page with `register_page`, the methods `content`, `columns` (inside content) `column` (inside columns) are available, and the `index` method is not
- when i create a page with `register <resource>` the `content`, `columns`, `column` methods are **not** available while the `index` method is available

Ideally, i want to add an `index` to pages created via `register_page`.

If this isn't achievable, then i want to find a workaround that allows to add panels in pages created via `register`.

I tryed with table_for method, but the result is quite different from the one obtained with index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that this is old, but I stumbled across it in my search for an answer and thought I would post up an answer for others:

If you want to use `index` inside a `register_page`, you can't.  You *can*, instead, provide `register` with a custom name in the style of `register_page` a la

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post, :as => "Special Articles"
```

This won't conflict with another `ActiveAdmin.register Post` and would allow you to put a scope on the `Post`s or something like that.